# How to add functionality to Mongoid::Document from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mongoid, mongoid3

I want to create a gem which adds some functionality to my models. How to define a custom keyword for a Mongoid model? E.g.:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_my_awesome_functionality
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a gem called `foobar` you can put the following into your gem's initialiser, or in a separate file (usually called `railtie.rb`[, just make sure it's being loaded]):

```
require 'foobar'
require 'rails'

class FooBar
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

  config.before_initialize do
    ::Mongoid::Document.module_eval do
      def self.included(base)
        base.extend FooBar::MongoidExtension
      end
    end
  end if defined?(Mongoid)
end
```

and your extension can look like this:

```
module Foobar::MongoidExtension
  def has_my_awesome_functionality
    # logic here
  end
end
```